# Bootstrap 3 Side Navigation Wrapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav

I have the following code that wraps the navigation text on the left side but not the text that I have pulled right:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row col-xs-12">
    <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-tab-block">
      <div class="panel-heading col-xs-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked flex-wrap">
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="" href="#portfolio-project-tab-NLPortfolio"> NLPortfolio <span
class="pull-right">0</span>
</a></li>
          <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" class="" href="#portfolio-project-tab-motion" aria-expanded="false">
Motion Sports <span class="pull-right">0</span>
</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="" href="#portfolio-project-tab-afxprem"> Premiere Sports <span
class="pull-right">0</span>
</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="" href="#portfolio-project-tab-prelude"> Prelude Sports <span
class="pull-right">0</span>
</a></li>
          <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" class="" href="#portfolio-project-tab-psp" aria-expanded="false">
Photoshop Project <span class="pull-right">1</span>
</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="" href="#portfolio-project-tab-audiptx"> ProToolsProject <span
class="pull-right">0</span>
</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="" href="#portfolio-project-tab-afx"> AFX Sports <span
class="pull-right">0</span>
</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="" href="#portfolio-project-tab-c4d"> Cinema4D <span
class="pull-right">0</span>
</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="" href="#portfolio-project-tab-audi"> AuditionProject <span
class="pull-right">0</span>
</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="" href="#portfolio-project-tab-ARCPortfolio"> ARCPortfolio <span
class="pull-right">0</span>
</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" class="" href="#portfolio-project-tab-SNPortfolio" aria-expanded="true">
SNPortfolio <span class="pull-right">0</span>
</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="" href="#portfolio-project-tab-fcpsports"> FCP Sports <span
class="pull-right">0</span>
</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="" href="#portfolio-project-tab-illu"> IllustratorProject <span
class="pull-right">0</span>
</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="" href="#portfolio-project-tab-avid"> AvidProject <span
class="pull-right">0</span>
</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body col-sm-10">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div id="portfolio-project-tab-NLPortfolio" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="portfolio-overview-block"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="portfolio-project-tab-motion" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="portfolio-overview-block"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="portfolio-project-tab-afxprem" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="portfolio-overview-block"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="portfolio-project-tab-prelude" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="portfolio-overview-block"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="portfolio-project-tab-psp" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="portfolio-overview-block">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="project-overview-card">
                  <div class="project-overview-card-content">
                    <div class="">
                      <label>Owner</label><span class="pull-right"> </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="portfolio-project-tab-audiptx" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="portfolio-overview-block"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="portfolio-project-tab-afx" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="portfolio-overview-block"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="portfolio-project-tab-c4d" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="portfolio-overview-block"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="portfolio-project-tab-audi" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="portfolio-overview-block"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="portfolio-project-tab-ARCPortfolio" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="portfolio-overview-block"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="portfolio-project-tab-SNPortfolio" class="tab-pane active">
            <div class="portfolio-overview-block"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="portfolio-project-tab-fcpsports" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="portfolio-overview-block"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="portfolio-project-tab-illu" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="portfolio-overview-block"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="portfolio-project-tab-avid" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="portfolio-overview-block"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The css is as follows:

```
.panel.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block {
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs > li > a,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #999999;
}

.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs > .open > a,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs > .open > a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs > .open > a:focus,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #666666;
}

.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2f70b1;
  border-color: #2f70b1;
}

.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #428bca;
  border-color: #3071a9;
}

.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}

.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #3071a9;
}

.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: #4a9fe9;
}
```

I have created [a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karencoding/w3nshh7f/).

The problem can be seen where the data that is pulled right sits under the left navigation text but gets cut off.  To see this issue change the size of the page. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Not quite sure what you want at the end, but you can maybe start [with this](https://jsfiddle.net/w3nshh7f/9/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for the suggestions. I was having a bit of a moment.

I ended up changing col-sm-2 to col-xs-3 col-lg-2 and respective div from col-sm-10 to col-xs-9 col-lg-10.